# Why is the emissive light flickering while the camera is in motion?

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, lighting

Why is the emissive light flickering while the camera is in motion?

Using Blender 3.1.2
[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MAY5TFALvPNfLm7XdhQKcvyXt5SVOkBQ/view?usp=sharing)
[image]

Comment: You have to specify your question a little bit. If it would be "flickering like crazy" after you rendered the animation, this would be strange. But I guess you are referring to flickering while watching in the _3D Viewport_. Well, the render engine might be relatively quick moving in realtime in the viewport, but still it needs to calculate the light emission new on each frame, and it takes its time. If you render it, the flickering is less - but even then, the glow is depending on the light values of the image pixels, and they change constantly when the image is moving.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GordonBrinkmann. I hear what you're saying, the flickering is considerably worse in the viewport but still incredibly noticeable and distracting in my renders. Do you know of any way to reduce the effect?
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turning off bloom in render settings and adding fog glow in the compositor instead solved the problem

Answer (score 3):

I know it's maybe not what you want but maybe you are fine with it:

if you make a very tiny loopcut and add the front faces to your chassis lights too, it won't flicker anymore. But of course it looks a bit different.

[image]

[image]

I can guess why it is flickering, you did only give emission to faces which are 90 (or nearly 90) degrees to your camera, so this is a pretty small face which is really being seen by the camera. Because of rounding and inaccuracy results with very small numbers this might be a problem for Blender to render this accurately.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @LuckyOne!
I tried your suggestion and I think it helped the flickering a little bit.
I'm pretty sure you're correct about Blender simply having trouble calculating the emission from a face 90 degrees perpendicular to the camera.

Comment: @Willsey It's not just the 90° angle (maybe in this case, but not in general), but rather the size due to rounding and inaccuracy as LuckyOne said. The amount of _Bloom_ (or similar with _Fog Glow_ added in the _Compositor_) is the larger an emission source is, so the stronger is the glow effect and the more "stable" it is. If you have a very thin line of emission (especially when this line is diagonal or curved instead of horizontal or vertical) the stronger the effect of antialiasing becomes, which makes the pixels darker and can change from frame to frame and cause strong flickering.

Comment: @Willsey By the way, while mentioning it in my comment before: I personally think when I deactivate _Bloom_ in _Eevee_ and instead add _Fog Glow_ (with quality set to _High_) in the _Compositor_, the flickering is less intense. Maybe this in combination with the workaround in this answer here might get better results.

Comment: Thank you for the insight and the tips @GordonBrinkmann!
I'll try your suggestion tomorrow.